# Platform-independent printing

Tags: ios, web, printing

I am working on a project that requires printing to work across platforms of a fairly complex form with fields that get filled out. I currently have an iPad version of it, which prints beautifully and works well. I am however worried as this works by designing the form in IB, then filling it with a UIViewController and then printing it. However, the app will have to get a web version in the very near future and it is incredibely important that whatever the device I use to print the form, it must look the same. This seems like an impossible task so I was wondering,

Do you know of a way how I can print a complex form that was originally designed in IB from web (and possible Win or Mac apps) so that it always looks the same on paper?

Thanks

Comment: Create a PDF and print that output.

Comment: Well sure, but the creating of the PDF to look the same from both iOS and web is the problem.

Comment: Obviously there are ways of rending web pages in an iOS app. iOS also provides api for printing such views

Comment: So you suggest designing the form on web, then rendering it on iOS and printing that? That actually sounds quite good, although it sucks somewhat that it would be impossible to print stuff from iOS without internet connection (I assume, right?)